# Copying and Renaming files with Parent Directory in

Tags: .net, powershell

I am a newb trying to apply this code in Powershell to copy and rename files to a different folder on Explorer with the parent directory included in the name with an added space in between :

Original

```
originalfilename.txt
```

New Name

```
parentfolder originalfilename.txt
```

When I try using the following code it does not work. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
$Root='C:\Users\Bart\Documents'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
$ParentOjbect = $_.Directory 
$Parent = $ParentOjbect.Name  
Copy-item -Destination (Join-Path $Root ('{0}{1}{2}' -f $Parent, " ", $_.Name)) }
```

Would really appreciate any help or expertise about this

Updated Code, assume variables are already instantiated and work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.Name -notcontains "Archive"}| 
ForEach-Object {
    if(!$_.PSIsContainer){
    $DateStr = $_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(3,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(6,4)  
    $FileDate = get-date $DateStr
    If ( $FileDate -ge $Date ) {
        Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $Src -ChildPath '\*' ) -Destination (Join-Path $Dst ("$($_.Directory.Name) $($_.Name)")) -WhatIf 
          #Dst is the same as $Root
    }}
}
```

Comment: I see you are a new user and already have a few down votes.  Don't let that discourage you, we all get downvoted from time to time.  There are already many questions and answers about copying files with powershell. I recommend going through those questions and answers first or split up your script into smaller tasks, first get copy working, then get renaming working, then you will know how to merge the two concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and encouragement. I really am not familiar with Powershell at all and this is my second day at my first programming internship. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: "*I have this code and it doesn't work*" is downvote territory because there are heaps of ways it might "not work" - from syntax error to logical misunderstanding to "I don't know how to use it" to "it runs but doesn't do what I expect", all with different fixes, and you need to say what you are seeing vs what you want to see. Your code 'works' - it's valid and it runs. I'm going to throw a guess that the prompt for a "Path" means `Copy-Item` doesn't know what it's supposed to be copying. You either need to pipe `$_ | Copy-Item..` or specify `Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName ...`

Comment: Thanks Tessellating Heckler, the path was included earlier with a Get-Child

Answer (score 0):

As TesselatingHeckler already pointed out `Copy-Item` needs a source object to act on.

If your current folder is the root folder the danger of an endless loop or reiterating processed items exists, so put the `Get.ChildItem -recurse` into parentheses.

The format expression
`'{0}{1}{2}' -f $Parent, " ", $_.Name` could be simplified:
`'{0} {1}' -f $Parent,$_.Name`

You should exclude directories from your gci, dependig on your powershell version with the `-File`parameter of gci or with `Where {!($_.PSIsContainer)} |`

Copy-item accepts piped input and as you can reference `$_.Directory.Name` directly there is no need for the ForEach and intermediate variables:

```
$Root = "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Documents"
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse) | Where {!($_.PSIsContainer)} |
    Copy-Item -Dest {Join-Path $Root ("$($_.Directory.Name) $($_.Name)")} -WhatIf
```

If the ouput looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` in the last line.

---

Starting in my testfolder with a tree:

```
> tree /F .
C:\TEST\2017
│   SO_16-51.ps1
├───06
│   ├───20
│   │   │   SO_44639321.cmd
│   │   │   SO_44639321.ps1
│   │   │   SYS_PURCHASES_20170617.xls
│   │   │   SYS_PURCHASES_20170618.xls
│   │   │   SYS_PURCHASES_20170619.txt
│   │   │   SYS_PURCHASES_20170619.xls
│   │   └───Destination
│   └───24
└───2017-01
    └───16
        │   get-Isocontent.ps1
        │   IsoDates.psm1
        │   IsoDateStuff.ps1
        │   Measure-IP.cmd
        │   Using-Isodates.ps1
        └───VM20
                test.csv
                test.txt
```

Running the script with $root on my empty ramdisk A:\

```
$Root = "A:\"
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse) | Where {!($_.PSIsContainer)} |
    Copy-Item -Dest {Join-Path $Root ("$($_.Directory.Name) $($_.Name)")}
```

Giving these resulting files on A:\

```
> tree /F A:\
A:\
    2017 SO_16-51.ps1
    20 SO_44639321.cmd
    20 SO_44639321.ps1
    20 SYS_PURCHASES_20170617.xls
    20 SYS_PURCHASES_20170618.xls
    20 SYS_PURCHASES_20170619.txt
    20 SYS_PURCHASES_20170619.xls
    16 get-Isocontent.ps1
    16 IsoDates.psm1
    16 IsoDateStuff.ps1
    16 Measure-IP.cmd
    16 Using-Isodates.ps1
    VM20 test.csv
    VM20 test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you LotPings, I am new to PS and am not familiar with the syntax. This is my first project ever with Powershell. Assume there is a source object, I posted the full version of my code somewhere else, I can link you to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804406/rename-and-copy-select-files-in-nested-directory-powershell

Comment: Completed the project. Thank you so much for your help LotPings

Comment: You should express your thank by voting up and/or check marking the answer if you found the answers helpful. This applies to both of your questions.

Comment: I will make sure to do that

Comment: LotPings, When I use your suggestion, I end up creating a folder with the filename and the extension included in that folder name instead of the renamed and copied file. Can you please help me understand why that happens and how to fix that?

Comment: For some odd reason it was working correctly the first time I tried it and then now just creates folders

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The script block in the copy command has to be included in curly braces not parentheses. I'll change the code immediatley.

Comment: Now the code does not function whatsover after updating my code to curly braces. Haha I'm a novice so I don't know anything about the syntax

Comment: This is my first project using Powershell ever. I don't even have a comp sci background

Comment: What does that change? When you change it from parentheses to curly brace? What does a script block do haha

Comment: I'll insert a test scenario in my answer.

Comment: Here is the error message it currently throws me using curly braces: Copy-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Destination' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no inpu
t. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.

Comment: Here is the host output with (): What if: Performing operation "Copy Directory" on Target "Item: C:\Users\Bart Zhang\Downloads\Test Folder\500 Destination: C:
\Users\Bart Zhang\Desktop\New folder\Archive 03-11-2016 Test Report.txt".

Comment: So I want it to copy the file instead of the directory, does that make sense? It's making folders with the file name and extension name

Comment: Thanks for including the test scenario, I'm looking at it right now

Comment: What exact powershell version do you use?  See `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: Major: 2 Minor: 0 Build: -1 Revision: -1

Comment: I should have asked earlier (actually working with v5.1 and 6beta3). I wasn't clear enaugh with the -File parameter - your version has to use the above changed `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse) | Where {!($_.PSIsContainer)} |`